# Send images from .php to ajax that are stored in the server

Tags: php, ajax, image

I have a code that send by ajax the id of a product to a php file.
In this php file I process the id of the product and I select, from a mysql db, all the paths of the images (which are on my localhost server)  that have the id of the product as foreign key (pid_fk). 
Actually the data that I select is:

-Id of the image (fid)

-Path of the image (url)

What I have:

The ajax file:

```
var datos = {
    cod: id //This is the id of the product
}
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/carga/adm_prodfotos.php",
    data : datos,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        //I'll catch the images here and to show on my website
    }

});
```

The php file:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['cod'])){
        $cod = $_GET['cod'];
    }
    else{
        $cod = '';
    }

    require_once("../../../php/DBClass.php");
    $db = new Cl_DBClass();
    $query = "SELECT fid, url FROM fotos WHERE pid_fk = $cod";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    while($fila = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        //Here I think I have to process the path and convert to something to send to the ajax file (Such an array)
    }


?>
```

So the problem are:

1) I don't know how to convert the path of the images to a "bundle" to send to ajax file.

2) I've to work on this "bundle" to convert in images to show.

Comment: if the data stored in the `url field` is really a `url` then you do not have to do anything and just putting it in the `src property` of and `img` element would do the trick for you. but if it's a physical path on the server, then you have to create the `url` of the image first(using the physical path) on server-side and then pass it to you `ajax` function call. also please do some research on `php json_encode`

Comment: @EhsanT Yes. I've just answered my own question, I did something similar. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great, have fun coding...

Comment: @EhsanT The same to you, and never forget to mix the work with fun as long as it can be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' ve just done it. It was easier that what I thought. 
What I did is select the path of the images and send as html.

The code: 
php:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['cod'])){
        $cod = $_GET['cod'];
    }
    else{
        $cod = '';
    }

    require_once("../../../php/DBClass.php");
    $db = new Cl_DBClass();
    $query = "SELECT fid, url FROM fotos WHERE pid_fk = $cod";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    $html = '';

    while($fila = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        $img = $fila['url'];
        $fid = $fila['fid'];
        $html .= <<<HTML
            <img data-id=$fid src="http://127.0.0.1/project/front/images/productos/$img" height='250' width='250'>

HTML;
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

Ajax:

```
$('#modal2').on("shown.bs.modal",function(e){
    var datos = {
        cod: id
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/carga/adm_prodfotos.php",
        data : datos,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#imagenes').html(result);
        }

    });
});
```

For if you need this is how I stored the url of the images in the db:

pid_fk/fid (Remember that pid_fk was the id of the product and fid the id of the image)

for example: 
1/image1.jpg